# PHP - What is expected by 'openssl_decrypt' function?

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, aes

(Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker)

I have encrypted data by AES-256-ECB, I use 'openssl_decrypt' function, but I always receive a false value.

```php
$encrypted = '86090e16c5d950a35efe801f8eb5201b';
$key = 'PasswordExample_PasswordExample_';
$text = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, 'aes-256-ecb', $key);
echo "Result: $text";
```

I tried with `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` option, and passing `$encrypted` and `$key` with `base64_encode()`, but nothing worked.

A friend is sending me this encrypted text by software and I can read the answer in this site: http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ (`.:Text example:.`), but I want to use PHP for an automated process.

Someone can help me? I don't think the PHP webpage has enough documentation about this function.

---

Update:

This test code shows my problem:

```php
<?php

$encrypted_hex = '86090e16c5d950a35efe801f8eb5201b';
$encrypted_str = pack("H*", $encrypted_hex);
$encrypted_64 = base64_encode($encrypted_str);

echo "Encrypted (str): '$encrypted_str'<br>\n";
echo "Encrypted (hex): '$encrypted_hex'<br>\n";
echo "Encrypted (64): '$encrypted_64'<br>\n";
echo "<br>\n";

$key_str = 'PasswordExample_PasswordExample_';
$key_hex = implode(unpack("H*", $key_str));
$key_64 = base64_encode($key_str);

echo "Key (str): '$key_str'<br>\n";
echo "Key (hex): '$key_hex'<br>\n";
echo "Key (64): '$key_64'<br>\n";
echo "<br>\n";

$result_str = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_str, 'aes-256-ecb', $key_str);
$result_hex = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_hex, 'aes-256-ecb', $key_hex);
$result_64 = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_64, 'aes-256-ecb', $key_64);

echo "Result (str): '$result_str'<br>\n";
echo "Result (hex): '$result_hex'<br>\n";
echo "Result (64): '$result_64'<br>\n";
echo "<br>\n";
```

The generated HTML is:

Encrypted (str): '� ��P�^���� '
Encrypted (hex): '86090e16c5d950a35efe801f8eb5201b'
Encrypted (64): 'hgkOFsXZUKNe/oAfjrUgGw=='

Key (str): 'PasswordExample_PasswordExample_'
Key (hex): '50617373776f72644578616d706c655f50617373776f72644578616d706c655f'
Key (64): 'UGFzc3dvcmRFeGFtcGxlX1Bhc3N3b3JkRXhhbXBsZV8='

Result (str): ''
Result (hex): ''
Result (64): ''

If I add `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` there is no change. The problem persists over Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (both with Apache 2 and PHP 7). Where is my error? Can someone show me an example of use with `aes-256-ecb`?

Comment: Your code should be decrypting the message correctly, though it's possible that `openssl_decrypt` is throwing an error due to it not being installed. Check for `extension=php_openssl.dll` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: It seems your ciphertext is hex encoded, if so you have to decode before decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decryption can be performed with:

```
$result = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($encrypted_hex), 'aes-256-ecb', $key_str, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
```

- Concerning the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`-flag: The [website](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/) uses [Zero-Byte-padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding), `openssl_encrypt/decrypt` [PKCS7-padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7). With the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`-flag the PKCS7-padding can be deactivated. Note that the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`-flag disables padding, it doesn't mean that Zero-Byte-padding is used (the name of the flag is somehow confusing), see [`openssl_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), *openssl at mailismagic dot com*'s comment. Zero-Byte-padding isn't directly supported by `openssl_encrypt/decrypt`, i.e. the Zero-Byte-padding must be implemented by the user. Since only decryption takes place on the PHP-side, only the un-padding (i.e. the removal of the zero-values at the end) must be done manually (which is currently missing in the PHP-code). For the current plaintext (`.:Text example:.`) the missing un-padding isn't noticed, because the plaintext is exactly one block (16 bytes) long, so that Zero-Byte-padding wouldn't take place during encryption (in contrast to PKCS7-padding where a complete block is appended).
- Concerning the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`-flag: The ciphertext isn't Base64-encoded, so the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`-flag must be set. Alternatively:

  ```
  $result = openssl_decrypt(base64_encode(hex2bin($encrypted_hex)), 'aes-256-ecb', $key_str, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
  ```

  can be used for decryption.
- Concerning the first parameter: Since the ciphertext is stored as hex-string, it must first be decoded (`hex2bin($encrypted_hex)` or `pack("H*", $encrypted_hex)`), as already noted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I noticed without `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` flag, the function expects a text with padding characters (with a value equal to the number of missing characters). At least one padding char is needed. But I can't edit the encrypted text and add that padding chars.

`OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` solved my specific situation.